# Google Analytics not updating

Tags: android, google-analytics

I've incorporated the latest Google Services library into my app,  and have added screen tracking using the code below:

```
GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);

    Tracker t = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);

    t.setScreenName(full_event);

    t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
```

My global tracker xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">300</integer>

<!-- Enable automatic Activity measurement -->
<bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">false</bool>

<!--  The following value should be replaced with correct property id. -->
<string name="ga_trackingId">[redacted]</string>
```

where I've used the "all apps" property tracking code.

I send a screen name update manually each time a user visits a particular screen in the app.

The real time updates show fine in the Google Analytics web page, but for some reason the historical reporting is not working. I've looked online and there is a suggestion that it can take 48 hours to show when you first set it up.  However I started sending analytics data on Monday and it's now Saturday and nothing is showing up.

Am I doing something wrong or should I just give it more time?

I don't have that many users of my app (a few hundred perhaps). Could it be that Google needs a certain volume of data before it shows any statistics?

Any thoughts gratefully received.

Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out what was wrong. My code above creates a new tracker every time a screen view is to be sent whereas you're only supposed to create one per instance of the app.

I also modified it so that it was sending back screen views based on each specific app (rather than the all apps code) as well as including code in my onStart and onStop methods to enable tracking of the app itself as well as exception handing etc.

All working now.